# How do I push a node project to GitHub that contains a create-react-app in a subfolder?

Tags: reactjs, git, github, create-react-app

I'm currently working on my first MERN app. I have some issues regarding pushing my app to GitHub. My app file structure is as follows:

```
├───myApp
│   ├───server.js
│   ├───connection.js
│   ├───controls
│   ├───models
│   ├───client  <-- create-react-app folder
```

I know that using create-react-app will run `git init` as well. So, if I try to get my full app on GitHub I will get a git repo inside a git repo:

[image]

Is there a way to remove git from the create-react-app and push my whole app to one repo?

Thanks

Comment: Why not just deleting `client/.git`?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can just delete the git folder in your create-react-app then you can add it to your main repository.  It is a hidden folder so you will have to show hidden files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed the issue by deleting the `.git` folder inside the client

Answer (score 0):

On github, you will be able to deploy only the react app. Not your backend. 
The easiest way is to deploy to a gh-branch branch the dist folder created by create-react-app when you run the build command.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But, I do not want to deploy my app yet. It's just for keeping track of my versions.

Comment: You can do en -Rf of the .git folder inside your client folder